XSLT to remove duplicate child nodes
I have a source input XML where I need to remove duplicate records based on two child nodes. I am new to XSLT and have been trying various methods in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 to accomplish this but have not been successful.
Source XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <EDI.Table name="EDI.Table">
        <Row>
            <GroupId>A</GroupId>
            <MemberAltId>ABC123</MemberAltId>
            <PatientSeqId>002</PatientSeqId>
            <TotalMemberDeductible>499.52</TotalMemberDeductible>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <GroupId>A</GroupId>
            <MemberAltId>ABC123</MemberAltId>
            <PatientSeqId>002</PatientSeqId>
            <TotalMemberOop>499.52</TotalMemberOop>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <GroupId>A</GroupId>
            <MemberAltId>DEF123</MemberAltId>
            <PatientSeqId>001</PatientSeqId>
            <TotalMemberOop>50.00</TotalMemberOop>
        </Row>
    </EDI.Table>
</DataSet>

I have looked at other XSLT examples that involve removing duplicates, but I can't seem to get my code to work. I have used the following XSLT to remove the duplicate nodes but it does not change the Source XML at all.
The XSLT 1.0 Code:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="kMemberId" match="//Row" use="concat(MemberAltId,'|',PatientSeqId)"/>

<xsl:template match="/EDI.Table">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kMemberId',concat(MemberAltId,'|',PatientSeqId))[1])]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

The XSLT 2.0 Code:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/EDI.Table">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@* | Row"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Row" group-by="MemberAltId">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="PatientSeqId">
               <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Expected Output XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <EDI.Table name="EDI.Table">
        <Row>
            <GroupId>A</GroupId>
            <MemberAltId>ABC123</MemberAltId>
            <PatientSeqId>002</PatientSeqId>
            <TotalMemberDeductible>499.52</TotalMemberDeductible>
            <TotalMemberOop>499.52</TotalMemberOop>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <GroupId>A</GroupId>
            <MemberAltId>DEF123</MemberAltId>
            <PatientSeqId>001</PatientSeqId>
            <TotalMemberOop>50.00</TotalMemberOop>
        </Row>
    </EDI.Table>
</DataSet>

If someone can help me achieve the above expected XML that would be greatly appreciated.

Please ask about either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both.

@michael.hor257k, thank you for the advice. Will make note of this for the future.

In XSLT 2.0 you can do:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="EDI.Table">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Row" group-by="concat(MemberAltId, '|', PatientSeqId)">
            <Row>
                <xsl:copy-of select="GroupId | MemberAltId | PatientSeqId"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/(TotalMemberDeductible | TotalMemberOop)"/>
            </Row>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


The main problems with your attempt are:
<xsl:template match="/EDI.Table">

This tries to match a root element named EDI.Table which doesn't exist, and:
<xsl:copy-of select="@* | Row"/>

This copies all Row elements before outputting the unique ones.

this solution works somewhat, but it doesn't give me the desired output. Is there a way to remove duplicate elements and collect all sub nodes together?

Please see the test in the added link above. How does my result differ from the expected output posted in your question?

I am expecting the TotalMemberDeductible and TotalMemberOop child nodes to be grouped with the first Row element.

Your question makes no mention of this and your stylesheet makes no attempt to perform such task. I have edited my answer to include this functionality, but it should have been stated from the beginning.

Sorry my question did not specify this.  I am new to XSLT so I didn't know how to make my stylesheet achieve the desired output. Your solution works. Thank you.
